# Trilateration and nonlienar least squares

Tags: python-3.x, least-squares, trilateration

I am trying to find user distances from beacon positions using trilateration. I am having a mean squared error function that I am trying to minimize using non-linear least squares but I am not getting correct results. Any help is appreciated. The code is below.

```
def mse(self, user_pos, positions, distances):
    mse = 0.0
    for pos, dist in zip(positions, distances):
        distance = great_circle((user_pos[0], user_pos[1]), (pos[0], pos[1])).meters
        mse += math.pow(distance - dist, 2.0)
    return mse/len(positions)

def least_squares_func(self, positions, distances):
    # Returns users coordinates
    return least_squares(self.mse, [0,0], args=(positions, distances)).x
```

Starting position in least_squares is [0,0]  but after changing it I am not getting much different results.

Input example:
positions = [(5.0, -6.0), (13.0, -15.0), (21.0, -3.0)]
distances = [8.06, 13.97, 23.32]

Answer (score -1):

great_circle is used for GPS where we deal with  an oblate spheroid for beacons you must used simple Euclidean metric to calculate the distance between  the user and each  beacons.